# Clave gpg por medio de ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, gpg

necesito ejecutar un script de un servidorA en un servidorB lo estoy haciendo por ssh(ssh 'ipServidorA' php /xxx/xxxx/script.php)por lo general el script en en el servidorA me pide una clave gpg que sin problema la puedo agregar, pero en al ejecutarlo en el ssh de otro servidorB no me da la opción de agregar la clave y de una me arroja error.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Añade cómo estás ejecutando el script en cada caso y el mensaje de error completo, sin resumirlo. Idealmente, todo va como texto para que otros puedan replicar tu problema y ayudarte. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).